# Fail2ban fails to recognize IP

Tags: linux, security, regex, fail2ban

I have a problem here where Fail2ban failed to recognize the IP, so I try to ban failed MySQL access, here are the **syslog** to be monitored

```
Sep  6 01:45:18 vps6XXXXX mysqld: 2019-09-06  1:45:18 140581192722176 [Warning] IP address '120.160.120.60' has been resolved to the host name '67.subnet120-160-120.speedy.telkom.net.id', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
Sep  6 01:45:18 vps6XXXXX mysqld: 2019-09-06  1:45:18 140581192722176 [Warning] Access denied for user 'global'@'120.160.120.60' (using password:YES)
```

But, fail2ban failed to read the IP address from *120.160.120.60* detected as *0.0.0.7* . The log files from **fail2ban.log** are as follows

```
2019-09-06 01:45:18,742 fail2ban.filter [3793]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: 7 = ['0.0.0.7'] 
2019-09-06 01:45:18,742 fail2ban.filter [3793]: INFO [mysql] Found 0.0.0.7
```

Here’s my  custom **filter.d mysql.conf** regex

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^.*\[Warning\] Access denied for user.*<HOST>.*\(using password: YES\)$
ignoreregex =
```

I’m unsure if this fail2ban fail to determine the IP or my regex fail do the job.

I would appreciate any suggestions or solutions towards this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Was that the real IP address or is it a fake?

Comment: It is my IP address 120.160.120.60 and not fake

Comment: disable DNS lookup, you wont need it, i dont use it since fail2ban exists...

Comment: I think i won't disable that, check out this article https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Hostnames_or_IP_Addresses

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression in original question resolves `<HOST>` to parts only:

- `IP_V4_RE`: `0.160.120.60`
- `DNS`: `0`

*(see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/search?q=IP_4_RE&unscoped_q=IP_4_RE for details on fail2ban internal expressions for `<HOST>`)*

When adjusting to the following, the host part will be considered correctly:

```
failregex = ^.*\[Warning\] Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' \(using password: YES\)$
```

The custom regular expression does not seem to consider other possibilities like e.g. defined in https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/filter.d/mysqld-auth.conf#L20

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:\d+ |\d{6} \s?\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )?\[\w+\] (?:\[[^\]]+\] )*Access denied for user '[^']+'@'<HOST>' (to database '[^']*'|\(using password: (YES|NO)\))*\s*$
```

Comment: Thank you, the first failregex you mention is working, but the failregex provided by fail2ban not working on my server, my log something like this

`Sep 24 13:16:50 vps000920 mysqld[1234]: 2019-09-24 13:16:50 8756 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

Although similar annoying dual timestamp issues are known (some services resp. syslog's writing double date-times, one ahead and another in message body), I've no idea why the format within log-message changes from system to system.

Anyway it should be fixed now (see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/50595b70fd4e2563ba816acf4877775eda36e248).

BTW. Your regex is a bit "vulnerable", because not anchored (`^.*` makes no sense) and contains catch-all's (`.*`) before and after `<HOST>`.